# Product image not showing in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-images

I have a specific product and its image is not shown in the front-end. In the admin panel in **Catalog->Manage Products->Images** I can see all the images of its configurable product. So I don't understand why is this only happening only to this specific product. Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT:** No exclude or remove is checked on the Images section. I tried to find the images on the server and they are there with ownership www-data:www-data

Comment: Does it happen after using magmi?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the productdetails-page in the adminpanel and check the "Store View" Settings on the left top. Explanation: Every product can have global settings (used for every store) and special settings for only one special Storeview.

So, if you change the image only for one special Storeview, your changes are not displayed in the frontend in every store. For that reason you have to change this storeview scope an save your image there. Maybe this helps ;-)

Comment: In the choose store view everything is set in the Default Values. So I'm not sure if this is it.

Comment: @Stefanos tried a full re-index and clearing any caches?

Answer (score 0):

Well after a long search I found that I had to add a label in the picture in the admin in **Catalog->Manage Products** and in the **Store View** of the Configurable product **Images** and add some label in the **Label** field. Weird enough because all the other products did not have any label but this one needed one.